# Trying to add NSString to NSMutableDictionary doesn't work

Tags: objective-c, nsmutabledictionary

I'm getting a name and a phone number from text fields, till here all is ok.
When I'm trying to add these data to my `NSMutableDictionary` nothing happens.

---

### ViewController.h

```
@property(strong,nonatomic) NSMutableDictionary *contacts;
```

---

### ViewController.m

```
- (IBAction)btnAdd:(id)sender {
    self.userName = self.name.text;
    self.userPhoneNumber = self.phoneNumber.text;
    [self addToDictionary:self.userName :self.userPhoneNumber];
    NSLog(@"ADDED: Key = %@, Value = %@", self.userName, self.userPhoneNumber);
    [self clearTextFields];
}

- (void)addToDictionary: (NSString*) _name: (NSString*) _phone{
    [self.contacts setObject:_name forKey:_phone];
}
```

---

### Error message

> local declaretion of '_name' hides instance variable

Comment: That warning is because you have an instance variable in your ViewController named `_name`, as well as an argument to your `addToDictionary` method also called `_name`. Change the one in `addToDictionary` to, say, `theName`

Comment: thanks for the tip, i'll do that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You most likely are not initializing your dictionary.

Add this to your `viewDidLoad` method:

```
self.contacts = [NSMutableDictionary new];
```

As far as the warning at the end, when you have a declared property, an iVar will automatically be created for you with the same name, but an _ added before.  I.E. if you have `name` as a declared property, then an instance variable called `_name` is created for you.  When you created your `addToDictionary:` method, you used the same name.  This prevents you from accessing the iVar so it warns you about it.  To get rid of the warning, replace `_name` and `_phone` with something else (like `newName` and `newPhone`).